# Cron reindexer always gets stuck in "processing" when reindexing catalog URL rewrites index

Tags: reindex

Every time Magento's cron runs the reindexer, it always gets stuck in Processing for the catalog url rewrites index. As a result, the reindexer stops and leaves the other indexes in "Reindex Needed".

However, if I run the indexer in SSH, it will finish.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2):

Check your logs. You may be getting a memory limit error, a timeout, or an integrity constraint violation from the database.

Answer (score 1):

It may be maximum execution time issue.As cron have run several process with it system so the indexing is stop before completing.